# Hair not pointing with normals

Tags: particles, hair

[image]

Does anybody know why the hair is acting this way? if i make a sphere the hair follows the normals. But not with the head of the bear, normals are ok and pointing away from faces

Comment: There's really nothing we can do for you unless you attatch a blend file. Try to use this website: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I already figured it out. I exported it with a wrong scale from C4D.